# Disable Automatic Gain control in Google Hangouts

Tags: audio, google-chrome, google-apps

I'm using the latest version of OSX with Google Chrome and Hangouts. I'm having trouble with the Hangout's automatic gain control, in that I don't want to use it. The gain control is too dumb to understand that we're using a table top mic and that background noise isn't relevant.

I have found guides that tell you to edit com.google.GoogleTalkPluginD.plist, and I've followed them to a T, but they haven't affected the issue. It seems that hangouts is now separated from the Google Talk Plugin. All the information related to this issue was from 2011, and hangouts have changed vastly since then.

Is there any new settings file? It seems like the only option might be an inline level mixer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension available for this: [Disable Automatic Gain Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-gain-co/clpapnmmlmecieknddelobgikompchkk)